# How to do a custom logic and redirect to another pages in react or nextjs with useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building  quiz application it has three pages(Junior, Senior, SuperSenior). based on the drop down selected by the user in the home page, I want to redirect the user to appropriate pages.

The way I do is create a common component verify.js and redirect the user.

In **verify.js**

```
const verify = ({router: {query}}) => {

     const router = useRouter()

     useEffect(() => {
      if(query.level === 'junior') return router.push('/junior')
      
      if(query.level === 'senior') return router.push('/senior')

      if(query.level === 'superSenior') return router.push('/super-senior')
     })

      return <h1>Loading...</h1>
}
```

The problem is I can't get back to the home page again. When I once selected.

Comment: recheck your spelling first - line 1: "qery" and line 5: "useEfect".

Comment: use `router.replace` instead of push, so whenever you press back it will go to the 2nd last of history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to push user to different routes you can either use the **Redirect** coming with react-router and the most easiest is the **useHistory** hook.

I will give an example of the **useHistory** hook

```
 import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
 
 const history = useHistory()
 const verify = ({router: {query}}) => {

     const router = useRouter()

     useEffect(() => {
      if(query.level === 'junior'){ history.push('/junior') }
  
      if(query.level === 'senior'){ history.push('/senior') }

      if(query.level === 'superSenior'){ history.push('/super-senior') }
     })

      return <h1>Loading...</h1>
}
```